# how to extract TSP tour from an unordered list of its component trips

Tags: matlab, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Here is the initial code:

```
n = 5;
trips = nchoosek(1:n,2);
x_tsp=[0;1;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;1];
```

So the unordered list of the component trips of some tour is given to us. Now we have to translate it to the actual tour, meaning an ordered traversal of the cities in TSP style. The below code does it. But it seems to use `for` loop and is repetitive. Can this be vectorized in fewer lines?

```
x_tsp = logical(round(x_tsp));
relevant_trips=trips(x_tsp,:);
tour=zeros(n+1,1);
r=randi(n);
tour(1)=relevant_trips(r,1);
tour(2)=relevant_trips(r,2);
tour(end)=tour(1);
for i=3:n
    relevant_trips(r,:)=[];
    [~,next_ind]=ismember(tour(i-1),relevant_trips);
    [r,c] = ind2sub(size(relevant_trips),next_ind);
    if c==2
        tour(i)=relevant_trips(r,1);
    else
        tour(i)=relevant_trips(r,2);
    end
end
```